# Angular 2 authguard relative redirects

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there a way to redirect with a relative path pattern in a authguard?

I tried it with

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private _router: Router,
                private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        this._router.navigate(['../../servers/'], {relativeTo: this._route});

        return false;
    }
}
```

which should redirect from `/projects/2/servers/71` to `/projects/2/servers/` but It always redirect it to `/servers` (When I do the same in a component it works fine).

Comment: What route is `this._route` pointing to?

Comment: Ok it pointing to "". So It make sense why I'm getting redirected to `/servers`. When I try it with the ActivatedRouteSnapshot I'm getting a `Argument of type '{ relativeTo: ActivatedRouteSnapshot; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationExtras'`

Comment: Sorry, don't know. Why are you not using the absolute path?

Comment: The path has a dynamic component with `/projects/:id/servers` so I need the id first to create the absolute path. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You could check if `this._route.firstChild()` returns something. This way you can navigate the route to the leaf segment.

Comment: `this._route.firstChild` is `null`

Comment: Does anyone have a workaround for this? I'm encountering the same problem

Comment: I answerd my own question with the workaround I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this with a little helper function. But this only works if you know the schema of the url.

```
/**
 * ATTENTION: RECURSIVE
 *
 * We are searching for the url "searchString" which comes before
 * the parameter we are really search.
 * E.g. if you have a url like "projects/:projectId/servers/:serverId
 * and you need the :projectId your 'searchString' is 'servers'
 */
function getUrlParameterByChild(searchString: string,
                                route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                                next: boolean = false): string {
    let url: string = route.url[0] ? route.url[0].path : '';

    if (!url && !route.parent) {
        throw new Error('Parameter not found in url');
    }

    if (next) {
        return url;
    }

    return getUrlParameterByChild(searchString, route.parent, url === searchString);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
this._router.navigate([
    'projects',
    getUrlParameterByChild('servers', route),
    'servers'
])
```

Answer (score 0):

**relativeTo** should also accept an **ActivatedRouteSnapshot**, looks like this might have been overlooked, in the meantime here is a workaround:

```
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      // if(...) {
        const segments = state.url.split('/');
        segments.pop();
        segments.shift();
        this.router.navigate(segments);
      // } else {
      //   return true;
      // }


}
```